# Compare columns in 400 different files

Tags: r

I have 400+ different `.txt` files.

They are named as `FILE20160501.txt, FILE20160502.txt, FILE20160503.txt, ..., FILE20170503.txt`.

I know that some columns were added or removed in the past. I want to check in which file it changed and how different it was from what I have right now (`FILE20170503.txt`).

My approach:

```
file_names <- list.files("/data/", pattern = ".*txt")
col_names <- lapply(file_names, 
                    function(x) as.data.frame(fread(x, colClasses = "character",  nrows = 0)))
```

But then I'm stuck here.

Here is an example:

```
write.csv(iris, "iris20160501.csv")
write.csv(iris[-1], "iris20170501.csv")
write.csv(iris[-2], "iris20170502.csv")

file_names <- list.files(pattern = "iris.*csv")

col_names <- lapply(file_names, 
                    function(x) as.data.frame(fread(x, colClasses = "character", nrows = 0)))
```

The result is this:

```
[[1]]
[1] V1           Sepal.Length Sepal.Width  Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[2]]
[1] V1           Sepal.Length Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[3]]
[1] V1           Sepal.Width  Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

The last result is what I have today. I want to have a way to see when the columns changed, ie, the colnames in `iris20170501.csv` are different from `iris20170502.csv`.

Comment: Clarifying question: you have 2 sets of 400 .txt files? The original ones and what you have now? Can you provide an example of like 10 .txt files?

Comment: @YannisVassiliadis I edited my question

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: with your code you have a list of header from your file. Now, you can make a function that compare two header and apply it to your list. 
You could use `setdiff` function, or `intersect`.

Comment: what result do you need?

Answer (score 1):

You could modify a bit you code to extract column names:

```
col_names <- lapply(file_names, 
                    function(x) colnames(as.data.frame(fread(x, colClasses = "character", nrows = 0))))
```

There is a `V1` included, but it doesn't really matter, as we'll look for the differences.
Let's say the second element of the list is your reference file, to check which additional columns are present in other files, you could do:

```
additional=lapply(col_names,function(x) setdiff(x,col_names[[2]]))
```

which returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Sepal.Width"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "Sepal.Width"
```

If you want to find which columns are present in your reference file and missing in your other files, you can do the reverse:

```
missing=lapply(col_names,function(x) setdiff(col_names[[2]],x))
```

which gives:

```
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "Sepal.Length"
```

EDIT: As per Yannis's suggestion below, you can assign the dates present in the filenames as names of the lists's elements for easier access.

```
names(additional)=gsub("\\D", "", file_names)
names(missing)=gsub("\\D", "", file_names)
```

Then access the elements as `missing$'20160501'` for example.

Comment: 's answer is great! Two minor additions. If you don't care if the columns were added or deleted, i.e. you only care about the differences, you can do `changes<- lapply(col_names,function(x) union(setdiff(x,col_names[[2]]), setdiff(col_names[[2]], x)))`. Second change is that if you actually care about the date of the change, add the following `names(changes)<- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", file_names))`, which adds the date as the name of the list element.

Comment: @YannisVassiliadis Thanks! It's a good idea to keep the dates as names of the lists, I've edited my answer to add your suggestion, though I've dropped the `as.numeric as I don't think it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try either, assuming your columns are named col_1, col_2, in your file_names dataframe:

```
file_names$Boolean_FILE_TEST <- file_names$col_1 ==  file_names$col_2
```

Use the equality operator " == ", not the assignment operator ( = ) or you will mess up your data. This equality will go through your column and write a column beside it with "TRUE" if the file names match, or "FALSE" if the filenames do not match.

Then you can run the table function through that column to see how many matches (TRUE) and how many mismatches (FALSE) there are. But you offset the order to begin with then they could all be wrong.

```
table(file_names$Boolean_FILE_TEST)
```

To see if there are any matches, regardless of if they match up do something like ...

```
intersect(file_names$col_1, file_names$col_2)
```

Try passing this through length, table, or summary to see how many matches there are.

```
length(intersect(file_names$col_1, file_names$col_2))

table(intersect(file_names$col_1, file_names$col_2))
```